# event.preventDefault not working everywhere?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

i made a chrome extension to get element from web pages by using click event listener on content page but preventDefault is working for few times only.

for example on [this website](http://groceries.asda.com/) when i click on the menu bar it redirects to the next page instead of preventing click action to happen.
this is my event listener in content.js

```
document.addEventListener('click', function xyz(e){
e.preventDefault();
//alert(e);
var target = e.target || event.srcElement;
var attributes = Array.prototype.slice.call(target.attributes).map(function(i)    {
    return [String(i.name)+": "+String(i.value)]
})
alert(attributes);
prompt("xpath1 :",getPathTo(target));
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method:"captureElement",data:attributes});   
},true)
```

how to stop click event from occuring !

Comment: Maybe `e.preventDefault()` doesn't work if the source element is a `span` inside an `a`?

Comment: Isn't this event handler using capture mode, as evidenced by the third parameter = true?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You either need to use `return false;` or use `e.preventDefault();` and `e.stopPropagation()` together. Because this will prevent event from bubbling up to the parent anchor tag.

Comment: i tried this but on this website then its not giving the clicked element details !

Comment: you tried 'return false;' ? Also, you should bind click event to `a` tags only probably. shouldn't you?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you attach the event handler on the document itself instead of some child. So if you click on a child element the event will be prevented only when it will reach the document through bubbling, but in the mean time it will have been triggered.